# Regex to match comma followed by whitespace?

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to make a ruby regex to match tags in the format `Toys, Cars, Some Other Topic` but I can't figure out how to make it so that it splits it at after a comma and white space after but not if there is whitespace in a tag

This is what I have come up with http://rubular.com/r/ptjeQ1KyoD but is wrong for now.

`/[\/,$\(\s+)]/`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just use `/,\s*/` (which is much simpler than what you've got!):

```
'Toys, Cars, Some Other Topic'.split /,\s*/
=> ["Toys", "Cars", "Some Other Topic"]
```

Comment: Thanks it was those `[]` that I had and it was not matching to what I needed. I use this and removed the brackets and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, the square brackets are for something else entirely. (e.g., `[a-e]` matches any single character between `a` and `e`).

Answer (score 6):

You should just use:

```
,\s+
```

This matches all commas followed by one or more whitespace characters, and doesn't match the spaces beyond `Some`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this before with `[,\s+]` but it didn't work, and when I removed the brackets this worked also. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the whitespace is required for a match, this is better than the accepted answer, since `\s+` will match **one or more** `\s` (whitespace) characters, while `\s*` will match **zero or more**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (/,/x) which split all strings with comma(,)

Check here

http://rubular.com/r/8XdjgLK19g

```
'Toys, Cars, Some Other Topic'.split(/,/x)
=> ["Toys", "Cars", "Some Other Topic"]
```

Answer (score -1):

> function Validate(txt) {
>               txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^, a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
>           }

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue